# Parse XML to Pandas DataFrame to CSV

Tags: python, xml, api, pandas, dataframe

I have tried multiple iterations of code to get this done but cant seem to find a good solution. Been at it for days.

Here is the XML data I am returning from an API:

```
 <response status="success"><result>
  <job>
    <tenq>14:00:42</tenq>
    <tdeq>14:00:42</tdeq>
    <tlast>16:00:00</tlast>
    <status>FIN</status>
    <id>123</id>
    <cached-logs>123</cached-logs>
  </job>
  <log>
    <logs count="20" progress="100">
      <entry logid="123">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/11/25 12:12:02</receive_time>
        <serial>123</serial>
        <seqno>123</seqno>
        <actionflags>123</actionflags>
        <type>Example</type>
        <subtype>Example</subtype>
        <config_ver>0</config_ver>
        <time_generated>2017/11/25 12:12:00</time_generated>
        <src>192.168.1.1</src>
        <dst>192.168.1.1</dst>
        <natsrc>192.168.1.1</natsrc>
        <natdst>192.168.1.1</natdst>
        <rule>Example</rule>
        <srcloc code="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255" cc="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255">10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255</srcloc>
        <dstloc code="United States" cc="US">United States</dstloc>
        <app>Example</app>
        <vsys>Example</vsys>
        <from>Example</from>
        <to>Example</to>
        <inbound_if>Example</inbound_if>
        <outbound_if>Example</outbound_if>
        <logset>Example</logset>
        <time_received>Example</time_received>
        <sessionid>Example</sessionid>
        <repeatcnt>1</repeatcnt>
        <sport>123</sport>
        <dport>80</dport>
        <natsport>123</natsport>
        <natdport>80</natdport>
        <flags>123</flags>
        <flag-pcap>no</flag-pcap>
        <flag-flagged>no</flag-flagged>
        <flag-proxy>no</flag-proxy>
        <flag-url-denied>no</flag-url-denied>
        <flag-nat>yes</flag-nat>
        <captive-portal>no</captive-portal>
        <non-std-dport>no</non-std-dport>
        <transaction>no</transaction>
        <pbf-c2s>no</pbf-c2s>
        <pbf-s2c>no</pbf-s2c>
        <temporary-match>no</temporary-match>
        <sym-return>no</sym-return>
        <decrypt-mirror>no</decrypt-mirror>
        <proto>tcp</proto>
        <action>Example</action>
        <cpadding>0</cpadding>
        <dg_hier_level_1>0</dg_hier_level_1>
        <dg_hier_level_2>0</dg_hier_level_2>
        <dg_hier_level_3>0</dg_hier_level_3>
        <dg_hier_level_4>0</dg_hier_level_4>
        <vsys_name>Legacy</vsys_name>
        <device_name>Example</device_name>
        <vsys_id>123</vsys_id>
        <bytes>463</bytes>
        <bytes_sent>393</bytes_sent>
        <bytes_received>70</bytes_received>
        <packets>4</packets>
        <start>Example</start>
        <elapsed>0</elapsed>
        <category>Example</category>
        <padding>0</padding>
        <pkts_sent>3</pkts_sent>
        <pkts_received>1</pkts_received>
        <session_end_reason>Example</session_end_reason>
        <action_source>Example</action_source>
      </entry>
      <entry logid="456">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/11/25 12:12:02</receive_time>
        <serial>Example</serial>
        <seqno>Example</seqno>
        <actionflags>Example</actionflags>
        <type>Example</type>
        <subtype>Example</subtype>
        <config_ver>0</config_ver>
        <time_generated>2017/11/25 12:12:00</time_generated>
        <src>192.168.1.1</src>
        <dst>192.168.1.2</dst>
        <rule>Example</rule>
        <dstuser>Example</dstuser>
        <srcloc code="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255" cc="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255">10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255</srcloc>
        <dstloc code="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255" cc="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255">10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255</dstloc>
        <app>Example</app>
        <vsys>Example</vsys>
        <from>Example</from>
        <to>Example</to>
        <inbound_if>Example</inbound_if>
        <logset>Example</logset>
        <time_received>Example</time_received>
        <sessionid>0</sessionid>
        <repeatcnt>1</repeatcnt>
        <sport>123</sport>
        <dport>123</dport>
        <natsport>0</natsport>
        <natdport>0</natdport>
        <flags>123</flags>
        <flag-pcap>no</flag-pcap>
        <flag-flagged>no</flag-flagged>
        <flag-proxy>no</flag-proxy>
        <flag-url-denied>no</flag-url-denied>
        <flag-nat>no</flag-nat>
        <captive-portal>no</captive-portal>
        <non-std-dport>no</non-std-dport>
        <transaction>no</transaction>
        <pbf-c2s>no</pbf-c2s>
        <pbf-s2c>no</pbf-s2c>
        <temporary-match>no</temporary-match>
        <sym-return>no</sym-return>
        <decrypt-mirror>no</decrypt-mirror>
        <proto>tcp</proto>
        <action>Example</action>
        <cpadding>0</cpadding>
        <dg_hier_level_1>0</dg_hier_level_1>
        <dg_hier_level_2>0</dg_hier_level_2>
        <dg_hier_level_3>0</dg_hier_level_3>
        <dg_hier_level_4>0</dg_hier_level_4>
        <vsys_name>Example</vsys_name>
        <device_name>Example</device_name>
        <vsys_id>0</vsys_id>
        <bytes>70</bytes>
        <bytes_sent>70</bytes_sent>
        <bytes_received>0</bytes_received>
        <packets>1</packets>
        <start>Example</start>
        <elapsed>0</elapsed>
        <category>Example</category>
        <padding>0</padding>
        <pkts_sent>1</pkts_sent>
        <pkts_received>0</pkts_received>
        <session_end_reason>Example</session_end_reason>
        <action_source>Example</action_source>
      </entry>
      <entry logid="789">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/11/25 12:12:02</receive_time>
        <serial>Example</serial>
        <seqno>Example</seqno>
        <actionflags>Example</actionflags>
        <type>Example</type>
        <subtype>Example</subtype>
        <config_ver>0</config_ver>
        <time_generated>2017/11/25 12:12:00</time_generated>
        <src>192.168.1.1</src>
        <dst>192.168.1.2</dst>
        <rule>Example</rule>
        <srcuser>Example</srcuser>
        <dstuser>Example</dstuser>
        <srcloc code="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255" cc="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255">10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255</srcloc>
        <dstloc code="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255" cc="10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255">10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255</dstloc>
        <app>Example</app>
        <vsys>Example</vsys>
        <from>Example</from>
        <to>Example</to>
        <inbound_if>Example</inbound_if>
        <outbound_if>Example</outbound_if>
        <logset>Example</logset>
        <time_received>Example</time_received>
        <sessionid>Example</sessionid>
        <repeatcnt>1</repeatcnt>
        <sport>123</sport>
        <dport>123</dport>
        <natsport>0</natsport>
        <natdport>0</natdport>
        <flags>Example</flags>
        <flag-pcap>no</flag-pcap>
        <flag-flagged>no</flag-flagged>
        <flag-proxy>no</flag-proxy>
        <flag-url-denied>no</flag-url-denied>
        <flag-nat>no</flag-nat>
        <captive-portal>no</captive-portal>
        <non-std-dport>no</non-std-dport>
        <transaction>no</transaction>
        <pbf-c2s>no</pbf-c2s>
        <pbf-s2c>no</pbf-s2c>
        <temporary-match>no</temporary-match>
        <sym-return>no</sym-return>
        <decrypt-mirror>no</decrypt-mirror>
        <proto>no</proto>
        <action>no</action>
        <cpadding>0</cpadding>
        <dg_hier_level_1>0</dg_hier_level_1>
        <dg_hier_level_2>0</dg_hier_level_2>
        <dg_hier_level_3>0</dg_hier_level_3>
        <dg_hier_level_4>0</dg_hier_level_4>
        <vsys_name>Example</vsys_name>
        <device_name>Example</device_name>
        <vsys_id>0</vsys_id>
        <bytes>299</bytes>
        <bytes_sent>104</bytes_sent>
        <bytes_received>195</bytes_received>
        <packets>2</packets>
        <start>Example</start>
        <elapsed>0</elapsed>
        <category>Example</category>
        <padding>0</padding>
        <pkts_sent>1</pkts_sent>
        <pkts_received>1</pkts_received>
        <session_end_reason>Example</session_end_reason>
        <action_source>Example</action_source>
      </entry>
    </logs>
  </log>
</result></response>
```

I would like the data to fit into a dataframe so I can write it to a csv with the following headers:

```
logid   
receive_time    
type    
src dst rule    
srcuser 
srcloc code 
src_cc  *NEW HEADER*
dstloc code 
dst_cc  *NEW HEADER*
app 
from    
to  
repeatcnt   
sport   
dport   
proto   
action  
bytes   
bytes_sent  
bytes_received  
packets start   
elapsed category    
pkts_sent   
pkts_received   
session_end_reason  
action_source
```

Here is an image of the way the table should look (Obviously needs all the data inserted):
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEYab.png)

I was able to get this partially working with a for loop,  but then i'd need an additional 29 loops and 29 df conversions to concat the remaining headers/data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("My_Data.xml")


a = []
b = []


for src in tree.findall('.//src'):
    a.append({'Source': src.text})


for domain in tree.findall('.//domain'):
    b.append({'Domain': domain.text})


df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(b)


result = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)
```

This is my very first post. I have looked through this site for years and it has helped me a ton. Thank you all for your help and hard work. Please let me know if you need additional information.

**UPDATE**

I am also having an issue with tags that do not exist in every response. For example, if 'type' didn't exist in the very first response, it would not be added to the header. If the second xml response contains this tag, it will throw an error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'type'

**UPDATED CODE**

This code posted in one of the responses works great, just need to modify it to work with the update above.

**FINAL UPDATE**

The code below works 100% for my use-case. You can see the full explanation in the selected answer within the comments section.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from collections import OrderedDict

doc = et.parse('LogEntryCSV.xml')

csv_data = []

fields =  ['logid', 'receive_time', 'type', 'src', 'dst', 'rule',
           'srcuser', 'srcloc', 'dstloc', 'app', 'from', 'to', 'repeatcnt', 
           'sport', 'dport', 'proto', 'action', 'bytes', 'bytes_sent', 
           'bytes_received', 'packets', 'start', 'elapsed', 'category', 
           'pkts_sent', 'pkts_received', 'session_end_reason', 'action_source']

for elem in doc.findall('.//entry'):    
    inner_dict = OrderedDict({k:None for k in fields})   # PRE-POPULATES TEMP DICT

    inner_dict['logid'] = elem.attrib['logid']

    for item in elem.findall('.//*'):
        if item.tag in fields:
            if item.tag=='srcloc':
                inner_dict['scrloc code'] = item.attrib['code']
                inner_dict['scr_cc'] = item.attrib['cc']

            elif item.tag=='dstloc':
                inner_dict['dstloc code'] = item.attrib['code']
                inner_dict['dst_cc'] = item.attrib['cc']

            else:
                inner_dict[item.tag] = item.text

    csv_data.append(inner_dict)

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, csv_data[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(csv_data)
```

Comment: there is probably more to your code than those 4 lines, could you please share the rest as well?

Comment: why dont you just write to CSV first and then convert that to dataframe, that would be more easy.  also u might want to have a look on below thread     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453372/how-to-loop-through-a-complicated-xml-structure-in-order-to-transform-it-to-a-pa/47455819#47455819

Comment: @user1767754 I posted the rest of the code. I know how to get it into a csv once all data are in DataFrames. Notice, I only looped 'src' and 'domain' for now. If I continued it this way, I would need to loop 30 different times for each section. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: You don't need to loop for all single element, you just have to get the `head` tag which is `entry` and then from there get it's childs.

Comment: Why use pandas? You can easily migrate data from XML to CSV. And this has been asked many times on python SO threads.

Comment: @Parfait I've searched all throughout SO and haven't found something that does it 'easily'. The ones I saw still require you to loop through everything. If you have a link to one that is easy please post it.

Comment: @user1767754 can you post a snippet of something that might work? I have tried to do something along those lines without the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using containers like list of dictionaries that are assigned within a `for` loop iteration through each child of *entry*. For attributes, `if` conditionals are used to parse the attribute instead of text value. `OrderedDict` is used to keep keys intact as they are filled in. No need for pandas as you should leave the library for actual data analysis not data wrangling.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from collections import OrderedDict

doc = et.parse('LogEntryCSV.xml')

csv_data = []

fields =  ['logid', 'receive_time', 'type', 'src', 'dst', 'rule',
           'srcuser', 'srcloc', 'dstloc', 'app', 'from', 'to', 'repeatcnt', 
           'sport', 'dport', 'proto', 'action', 'bytes', 'bytes_sent', 
           'bytes_received', 'packets', 'start', 'elapsed', 'category', 
           'pkts_sent', 'pkts_received', 'session_end_reason', 'action_source']

for elem in doc.findall('.//entry'):    
    inner_dict = OrderedDict({k:None for k in fields})   # PRE-POPULATES TEMP DICT

    inner_dict['logid'] = elem.attrib['logid']

    for item in elem.findall('.//*'):
        if item.tag in fields:
            if item.tag=='srcloc':
                inner_dict['scrloc code'] = item.attrib['code']
                inner_dict['scr_cc'] = item.attrib['cc']

            elif item.tag=='dstloc':
                inner_dict['dstloc code'] = item.attrib['code']
                inner_dict['dst_cc'] = item.attrib['cc']

            else:
                inner_dict[item.tag] = item.text

    csv_data.append(inner_dict)

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, csv_data[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(csv_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have attempted to run this on my prod instance and encountered an issue. It appears that they're 2 additional fields that populate in some of the xml responses. The 2 fields are <natsrc> and <natdst>. I don't need these fields and they don't appear each time. Is there a way to ignore them? Right now it is throwing the error:ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'natdst', 'natsrc'

Comment: Add an `if` conditional to bypass: `if item.tag != 'natdst' and item.tag != 'natsrc': ...`

Comment: How would you recommend I predefine the headers? For example, they're more tags like 'natdst' that exist that I do need, but aren't always present in each xml response. The way this is structured right now, is it takes the headers from the first xml response. This will throw an error if 'logid' didn't exist in the xml response, but existed in the second. The way I think we can resolve this is with predefined headers that map through the loop, and maybe have a NaN or blank value for where it doesn't exist.

Comment: Consider the opposite then and proactively look for tags you do expect. See update.

Comment: Awesome, I think this sums it up and works as intended. Thank you for all your help! I will study this code a bit to understand it a bit better.

Comment: Excellent! Happy coding. Glad to help.

Comment: I am still getting errors when the values don't exist in the first response, but do in others that follow. Unfortunately, the headers that will be in each response may be dynamic. How do you recommend I solve this issue? I was hoping that it would just write a NaN value since the headers are predefined, but that's not the case, it throws: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'srcuser' Even though srcuser exists in the next response.

Comment: Please post such an example XML. In future always post near your actual and not simplified version.

Comment: I have added the extended/edited the XML in my original post. As you can see, each response contains similar and different headers. I either need to find a way to add them dynamically as they appear and create NaN values in the csv table for where they don't, or specify only the headers I want and create NaN values in the table for the responses that do not contain that specific header data.

Comment: See update. This time the *inner_dict* pre-populates keys by field names to `None` and the loop updates if key shows in XML. Be sure to include the `if item.tag in` which I noticed you above example did not include per my last update.

Comment: That worked! Thanks again for all your help. I finally understand how this code works.